# Как выровнять элементы списка если в списке первый элемент - картинка?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, list, меню

Не могу выровнять текст по центру относительно высоты картинки.
Пробовал `vertical-align:middle;` но скорее всего, я что-то не так делал.

```css
header>nav>ul
{
  padding-top: 2.5%;
}
header>nav>ul>li
{
  font-size: 1.25em;
  color: #6c6c6c;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  float: right;
}
header>nav>ul>li:first-child
{
}
```

```html
<header>
<nav>
<ul>
  <li><img src="http://blogs.slj.com/connect-the-pop/files/2013/05/Theatrics-logo-small.png" alt=""></li>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Products</li>
  <li>Services</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  padding: 0;

  font-size: 1.25em;
  color: #6c6c6c;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

li {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
<nav>
<ul>
  <li><img src="http://blogs.slj.com/connect-the-pop/files/2013/05/Theatrics-logo-small.png" alt=""></li>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Products</li>
  <li>Services</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
ul {
  text-align: justify;
  direction: rtl;
  padding: 0;

  font-size: 1.25em;
  color: #6c6c6c;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  direction: ltr;
}

ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
<nav>
<ul>
  <li><img src="http://blogs.slj.com/connect-the-pop/files/2013/05/Theatrics-logo-small.png" alt=""></li>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Products</li>
  <li>Services</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Очень рекомендую использовать flexbox для различных выравниваний. С ним жизнь становится прекрасна!

```
header>nav>ul
{
  padding-top: 2.5%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
header>nav>ul>li
{
  font-size: 1.25em;
  color: #6c6c6c;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: block;

}
```

Comment: Что-то вряд ли... Это ж на контейнере должно висеть?